# How to Display a UIImage View in another interFace Builder ?

Tags: xcode, interface, uiimageview, builder

hye guys

I'm working on a app that on the menu there is two buttons that one of them opens the Camera and use it in a ImageView and the other button makes you choose an image from the iPhone library and display it in the same ImageView.

i know how to display it in the imageViewer but its in the same interface builder , i don't want that .

I want in the first view (1st interface builder) only two buttons , and i want them bouth to display the image so i can Edit it later on in another View (2nd Interface Builder) , but i really stuck in that one :/

I Really don't know what to put in the .h + .m , in the new or secound view controller . any Help please ?

looking forward for any replay , thanks ;p

Answer (score 0):

Hiii,
    Simply store the image in the image object of your new class and just use in its imageview.